# How to change key mapping for a specific language?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, language, keymap

I'm on windows xp, sp3.

I use two languages, English and Serbian. When I write in Serbian "z" and "y" switch their keys. When I press the "z" key I get "y" as output and vica versa.

This is extremely annoying as every time I change languages I need to adapt to new mapping. Is there a way to change key mapping for a specific language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what is happening is that your keyboard layout is being changed when you switch languages. All you need to do is to change your Serbian keyboard to a custom keyboard of your making.

To create a custom keyboard use [this tool from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to duplicate your Serbian keyboard and then edit the <kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>y</kbd> keys to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry if the labels are incorrect, I am using a Spanish version...*

Control Panel, Regional settings, Languages (2nd) pane, Settings (top) button, leads you to a new box about *Text services and input languages*; in your case you should see two entries, one for Serbian and one for English. You need to make sure you are using the same "keyboard layout" for each of your "locale" you are using. I do not know if you'll prefer to use the Qwertz-based (Serbian) as it will give access to Serbian diacritics, or the Qwerty-based "US-international" and heavy blind use of AltGr: this is up to you!
To change the layout for a given language, you need to *add* the same language with the layout you want, then *remove* the layout you do not want. Perhaps the actual removing will be delayed to the next boot, such a message would be harmless.

Comment: thanks (: but peanut_butters solution not only solved my problem but enrichened the typing experience (as it allows me to map whatever, however)